# Probability of at least 3-of-a-kind in a 7-card poker hand

Tags: probability, poker

This problem asks to explain why the method used is overcounting or undercounting cards in a 7-card poker hand that contains at least two 3-of-a-kind (3-of-a-kind means three cards of the same rank) and calculate the correct probability.For example, this would be a valid hand: ace of hearts, ace of diamonds, ace of spaces, 7 of clubs, 7 of spades, 7 of hearts and queen of clubs. (Note that a hand consisting of all 4 aces and three of the 7s is also valid.). The $P_1(E)$ answer is given and basically we have to refute it. My answer is that the correct answer is $P_2(E)$ but cannot really grasp why the first one is wrong and if it is overcounting or undercounting cards.

$P_1(E) = \frac{{13\choose 2}{4\choose 3}{4\choose 3}{46\choose 1}}{{52\choose 7}}$ or $P_2(E) = \frac{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{12\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{46\choose 1}}{{52\choose 7}}$ .

Any explanations on this would be really helpful.

Comment: What is the difference between the hands AAA777Q and 777AAAQ?  If I were to give you some cards mixed up, for instance 7AAQ77A... which of those was the "*first*" triple and which was the "*second*" triple?

Comment: The first answer was the correct one.  The second was incorrect.

Comment: $P_1(E)$ they have said is incorrect we just have to refute why. Not sure what you mean exactly but im still confused .If we get the cards 7AAQ77A we still have two triples in our hand. Does the order we acquire these triples really matters?

Comment: And also the question mentions that "Note that a hand consisting of all 4 aces and three of the 7s is also valid" so not sure how you explain this case, as the question you prompted me to look does not take this as a case

Comment: "*Does the order we acquire these triples really matter?*"  No.  It doesn't.  Many times in probability, we can either treat order as relevant or irrelevant and get the same final answer.  However... whatever choice we make, we must be consistent.  If we treat order as mattering in the numerator, we need to keep it the same way for the denominator and vice versa.

Comment: Fine, if you allow for one four-of-a-kind and one triple as being valid, then both answers are wrong.  Add $13\cdot 12\cdot 4/\binom{52}{7}$ to the total to account for this additional case.  In fact... upon closer inspection, both answers are wrong anyways as they used $\binom{46}{1}$ rather than $\binom{44}{1}$.

Comment: I will look at it and update when i get the correct answer. Also, in several posts about this question $P_2(E)$ is marked as the correct answer and i still dont get what is wrong with this logic. You choose one rank and then 3 cards from it then from the remaining 12 ranks you choose 1 and then 3 cards from it and from the remaining 46 cards you choose 1 because you simply dont care if its the same rank with the previous two.

Comment: The point being, the answer given in $P_2$ could be explained as "*Pick the* **first** *rank used for a triple.  Pick the suits used for the first triple.  Then pick the* **second** *rank used for a triple and the suits used for it.  Finally pick the remaining card*"  However, since order doesn't matter, there is no way to distinguish between a "first" and "second" rank used and so they double-counted.  Then using $\binom{46}{1}$ this is supposedly attempting to allow the fourth of one of the triples as the final card, but this overcounts as well since we couldn't tell which was the fourth.

Comment: Deleting and rewriting earlier comment, the *actually correct* final answer of the probability there are two ranks each of which having at least three of that rank appearing (*i.e. a triple, another triple, and a kicker different than either, or a quad and a triple*) will be $$\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{3}\binom{44}{1} + \binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{4}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$

Comment: If you need further convincing, then consider the following incredibly similar problem.  You have a deck of merely four cards.  $A\spadesuit, A\heartsuit, K\spadesuit, K\heartsuit$.  When drawing four of the cards, you ask what the probability is that you got a two-pair, that is two cards each of two different suits.  Now... this is a particularly simple question if we approach directly... there is only one possible hand we could have drawn and that hand satisfies our desired form... so we have a probability of $100\%$.

Comment: According to our broken logic for $P_2$ here however, we'd have a probability of $\dfrac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{4}{4}}=2$... impossible.

Comment: "*In several posts about this question $P_2(E)$ is marked as the correct answer*"  If they are posts here, share the links so that people who actually know what they are talking about can correct their mistakes and set the record straight.  That should never have happened.

Comment: @JMoravitz you should flag this question to be reopened i will throw a vote for it. It is a different question state that order matters in the edit.

Comment: The reason why your statement is incorrect is because you are actually correct the way the problem is stated. The problem lies in the fact that the problem wants it to be different if you draw a tripe of 4's then 7's vs drawing a triple of 7's then a triple of 4's which is stupid because you have the same hand in poker. This is the reason why the second answer is twice as much as the first. I would explain better but there's not alot of room in a comment.

Comment: @Faust order neither matters nor doesn't matter. You can treat it as though order matters and get the same answer as though you treated it as order doesn't matter. You merely need to be consistent throughout the problem with whatever your choice.

Comment: I think it would be nice if we could post on this problem as i think is not duplicate and as @Faust mentioned the comments dont really help conveying your point